# JQ move(or copy) key value pairs to another object if a key/value pair meets condition in that object

Tags: arrays, json, object, jq

I have two files, they are very large so I will give a snippet of relevant data:

from_file:

```
  [
    {
      "id": 7212486534162308,
      "rowNumber": 283,
      "cells": [
        {
          "Column": "SS name",
          "columnId": 7408953102493572,
          "displayValue": "Dd Kk",
          "linkInFromCell": {
            "status": "OK",
            "sheetId": 4409864198875012,
            "rowId": 5483738575202180,
            "columnId": 6482434207311748,
            "sheetName": "INFORMATION - J-1000579"
          },
          "value": "Dd Kk"
        },
        {
          "Column": "link",
          "columnId": 5822630258337668,
          "displayValue": "Dd Kk link",
          "hyperlink": {
            "url": "https://app.test.com/fvffvs/dfesfrfr"
          },
          "linkInFromCell": {
            "status": "OK",
            "sheetId": 316850291664772,
            "rowId": 6836472364722052,
            "columnId": 6189414452881284,
            "sheetName": "PROJECT INTAKE SHEET"
          },
          "value": "Dd Kk"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 7046413570598788,
      "rowNumber": 284,
      "cells": [
        {
          "Column": "SS name",
          "columnId": 7408953102493572,
          "displayValue": "Macquarie Education Programs",
          "linkInFromCell": {
            "status": "OK",
            "sheetId": 8275059887368068,
            "rowId": 8307181892986756,
            "columnId": 687741640959876,
            "sheetName": "INFORMATION - J-1000532.01"
          },
          "value": "Macquarie Education Programs"
        },
        {
          "Column": "link",
          "columnId": 5822630258337668,
          "displayValue": "Macquarie Education Programs Building - J-10005",
          "hyperlink": {
            "url": "https://app.test.com/jnjnnlkm/fvfbsfbfgvdsfe"
          },
          "linkInFromCell": {
            "status": "OK",
            "sheetId": 316850291664772,
            "rowId": 4795289157298052,
            "columnId": 6189414452881284,
            "sheetName": "PROJECT INTAKE SHEET"
          },
          "value": "Macquarie Education Programs - J-10005"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

to_file:

```
[
  {
    "id": 977325251291012,
    "cells": [
      {
        "columnId": 2040705442965380,
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5206337428711300,
        "value": ""
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5460306864433028,
        "value": "Dd Kk",
        "displayValue": "Dd Kk"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5480924878661508,
    "cells": [
      {
        "columnId": 2040705442965380,
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5206337428711300
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5460306864433028,
        "value": "Macquarie Education Programs",
        "displayValue": "Macquarie Education Programs"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

in the to_file, inside each object that contains "columnId": 5206337428711300 I need to add all the key value pairs (except for "Column" and "columnId") from the from_file "columnId": 5822630258337668 containing object where that array of cell's "columnId": 7408953102493572 containing object has the same "displayValue" value as the to_file's "columnId": 5460306864433028 containing objects "displayValue" value.

desired outcome below:

```
[
  {
    "id": 977325251291012,
    "cells": [
      {
        "columnId": 2040705442965380,
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5206337428711300,
        "displayValue": "Dd Kk link",
        "hyperlink": {
          "url": "https://app.test.com/fvffvs/dfesfrfr"
        },
        "linkInFromCell": {
          "status": "OK",
          "sheetId": 316850291664772,
          "rowId": 6836472364722052, 
          "columnId": 6189414452881284,
          "sheetName": "PROJECT INTAKE SHEET"
        },
        "value": "Dd Kk"

      },
      {
        "columnId": 5460306864433028,
        "value": "Dd Kk",
        "displayValue": "Dd Kk"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5480924878661508,
    "cells": [
      {
        "columnId": 2040705442965380,
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5206337428711300,
        "displayValue": "Macquarie Education Programs Building - J-10005",
        "hyperlink": {
          "url": "https://app.test.com/jnjnnlkm/fvfbsfbfgvdsfe"
        },
        "linkInFromCell": {
          "status": "OK",
          "sheetId": 316850291664772,
          "rowId": 4795289157298052,
          "columnId": 6189414452881284,
          "sheetName": "PROJECT INTAKE SHEET"
        },
        "value": "Macquarie Education Programs - J-10005"
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5460306864433028,
        "value": "Macquarie Education Programs",
        "displayValue": "Macquarie Education Programs"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Thanks

@PMF answer below works but will fail if there is an item in the to_file that can't be found in the from file.

this works
[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Z_Eb59BlxM)

```
[
    {
    "id": 7660296628791172,
    "rowNumber": 484,
    "cells": [
      {
        "Column": "SS name",
        "columnId": 7408953102493572,
        "displayValue": "CSNSW",
        "linkInFromCell": {
          "status": "OK",
          "sheetId": 3495076589528964,
          "rowId": 4453675823982468,
          "columnId": 6210919910926212,
          "sheetName": "INFORMATION - J-1000739.01"
        },
        "value": "CSNSW"
      },
      {
        "Column": "link",
        "columnId": 5822630258337668,
        "displayValue": "CSNSW - J-1000739.01",
        "hyperlink": {
          "url": "https://app.test.com/beffvfdcwe/ergrsvsrfv"
        },
        "linkInFromCell": {
          "status": "OK",
          "sheetId": 3495076589528964,
          "rowId": 4655985963493252,
          "columnId": 6210919910926212,
          "sheetName": "INFORMATION - J-1000739.01"
        },
        "value": "CSNSW - J-1000739.01"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 7212486534162308,
    "rowNumber": 283,
    "cells": [
      {
        "Column": "SS name",
        "columnId": 7408953102493572,
        "displayValue": "Dd Kk",
        "linkInFromCell": {
          "status": "OK",
          "sheetId": 4409864198875012,
          "rowId": 5483738575202180,
          "columnId": 6482434207311748,
          "sheetName": "INFORMATION - J-1000579"
        },
        "value": "Dd Kk"
      },
      {
        "Column": "link",
        "columnId": 5822630258337668,
        "displayValue": "Dd Kk link",
        "hyperlink": {
          "url": "https://app.test.com/fvffvs/dfesfrfr"
        },
        "linkInFromCell": {
          "status": "OK",
          "sheetId": 316850291664772,
          "rowId": 6836472364722052,
          "columnId": 6189414452881284,
          "sheetName": "PROJECT INTAKE SHEET"
        },
        "value": "Dd Kk"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 7046413570598788,
    "rowNumber": 284,
    "cells": [
      {
        "Column": "SS name",
        "columnId": 7408953102493572,
        "displayValue": "Macquarie Education Programs",
        "linkInFromCell": {
          "status": "OK",
          "sheetId": 8275059887368068,
          "rowId": 8307181892986756,
          "columnId": 687741640959876,
          "sheetName": "INFORMATION - J-1000532.01"
        },
        "value": "Macquarie Education Programs"
      },
      {
        "Column": "link",
        "columnId": 5822630258337668,
        "displayValue": "Macquarie Education Programs Building - J-10005",
        "hyperlink": {
          "url": "https://app.test.com/jnjnnlkm/fvfbsfbfgvdsfe"
        },
        "linkInFromCell": {
          "status": "OK",
          "sheetId": 316850291664772,
          "rowId": 4795289157298052,
          "columnId": 6189414452881284,
          "sheetName": "PROJECT INTAKE SHEET"
        },
        "value": "Macquarie Education Programs - J-10005"
      }
    ]
  }
]
[
  {
    "id": 977325251291012,
    "cells": [
      {
        "columnId": 2040705442965380,
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5206337428711300,
        "value": ""
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5460306864433028,
        "value": "Dd Kk",
        "displayValue": "Dd Kk"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5480924878661508,
    "cells": [
      {
        "columnId": 2040705442965380,
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5206337428711300
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5460306864433028,
        "value": "Macquarie Education Programs",
        "displayValue": "Macquarie Education Programs"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

this doesn't work
[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/KF165obu6f)

```
[
    {
    "id": 7660296628791172,
    "rowNumber": 484,
    "cells": [
      {
        "Column": "SS name",
        "columnId": 7408953102493572,
        "displayValue": "CSNSW",
        "linkInFromCell": {
          "status": "OK",
          "sheetId": 3495076589528964,
          "rowId": 4453675823982468,
          "columnId": 6210919910926212,
          "sheetName": "INFORMATION - J-1000739.01"
        },
        "value": "CSNSW"
      },
      {
        "Column": "link",
        "columnId": 5822630258337668,
        "displayValue": "CSNSW - J-1000739.01",
        "hyperlink": {
          "url": "https://app.test.com/beffvfdcwe/ergrsvsrfv"
        },
        "linkInFromCell": {
          "status": "OK",
          "sheetId": 3495076589528964,
          "rowId": 4655985963493252,
          "columnId": 6210919910926212,
          "sheetName": "INFORMATION - J-1000739.01"
        },
        "value": "CSNSW - J-1000739.01"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 7212486534162308,
    "rowNumber": 283,
    "cells": [
      {
        "Column": "SS name",
        "columnId": 7408953102493572,
        "displayValue": "Dd Kk",
        "linkInFromCell": {
          "status": "OK",
          "sheetId": 4409864198875012,
          "rowId": 5483738575202180,
          "columnId": 6482434207311748,
          "sheetName": "INFORMATION - J-1000579"
        },
        "value": "Dd Kk"
      },
      {
        "Column": "link",
        "columnId": 5822630258337668,
        "displayValue": "Dd Kk link",
        "hyperlink": {
          "url": "https://app.test.com/fvffvs/dfesfrfr"
        },
        "linkInFromCell": {
          "status": "OK",
          "sheetId": 316850291664772,
          "rowId": 6836472364722052,
          "columnId": 6189414452881284,
          "sheetName": "PROJECT INTAKE SHEET"
        },
        "value": "Dd Kk"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 7046413570598788,
    "rowNumber": 284,
    "cells": [
      {
        "Column": "SS name",
        "columnId": 7408953102493572,
        "displayValue": "Macquarie Education Programs",
        "linkInFromCell": {
          "status": "OK",
          "sheetId": 8275059887368068,
          "rowId": 8307181892986756,
          "columnId": 687741640959876,
          "sheetName": "INFORMATION - J-1000532.01"
        },
        "value": "Macquarie Education Programs"
      },
      {
        "Column": "link",
        "columnId": 5822630258337668,
        "displayValue": "Macquarie Education Programs Building - J-10005",
        "hyperlink": {
          "url": "https://app.test.com/jnjnnlkm/fvfbsfbfgvdsfe"
        },
        "linkInFromCell": {
          "status": "OK",
          "sheetId": 316850291664772,
          "rowId": 4795289157298052,
          "columnId": 6189414452881284,
          "sheetName": "PROJECT INTAKE SHEET"
        },
        "value": "Macquarie Education Programs - J-10005"
      }
    ]
  }
]
[
  {
    "id": 977325251291012,
    "cells": [
      {
        "columnId": 2040705442965380,
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5206337428711300,
        "value": ""
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5460306864433028,
        "value": "Dd Kk",
        "displayValue": "Dd Kk"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5480924878661508,
    "cells": [
      {
        "columnId": 2040705442965380,
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5206337428711300
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5460306864433028,
        "value": "Macquarie Education Programs",
        "displayValue": "Macquarie Education Programs"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 7276986526263172,
    "cells": [
      {
        "columnId": 2040705442965380,
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5206337428711300
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5460306864433028,
        "value": "Dubbo",
        "displayValue": "Dubbo"
      }      
    ]
  }
]
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build an `INDEX` on a matching `displayValue`, and then `JOIN` the arrays by updating `+=` the right object in `to.json` with the corresponding object in `from.json`:

FIXED: Using `try` in the join update prevents from failing if the matching is not complete.

```sh
jq '
  [
    JOIN(
      INDEX(.[].cells; .[] | select(.columnId == 7408953102493572).displayValue);
      input[];
      .cells[] | select(.columnId == 5460306864433028).displayValue;
      (.[0].cells[] | select(.columnId == 5206337428711300)) += try
        (.[1][] | select(.columnId == 5822630258337668) | del(.Column, .columnId))
    )[0]
  ]
' from.json to.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "id": 977325251291012,
    "cells": [
      {
        "columnId": 2040705442965380,
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5206337428711300,
        "value": "Dd Kk",
        "displayValue": "Dd Kk link",
        "hyperlink": {
          "url": "https://app.test.com/fvffvs/dfesfrfr"
        },
        "linkInFromCell": {
          "status": "OK",
          "sheetId": 316850291664772,
          "rowId": 6836472364722052,
          "columnId": 6189414452881284,
          "sheetName": "PROJECT INTAKE SHEET"
        }
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5460306864433028,
        "value": "Dd Kk",
        "displayValue": "Dd Kk"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 5480924878661508,
    "cells": [
      {
        "columnId": 2040705442965380,
        "value": true
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5206337428711300,
        "displayValue": "Macquarie Education Programs Building - J-10005",
        "hyperlink": {
          "url": "https://app.test.com/jnjnnlkm/fvfbsfbfgvdsfe"
        },
        "linkInFromCell": {
          "status": "OK",
          "sheetId": 316850291664772,
          "rowId": 4795289157298052,
          "columnId": 6189414452881284,
          "sheetName": "PROJECT INTAKE SHEET"
        },
        "value": "Macquarie Education Programs - J-10005"
      },
      {
        "columnId": 5460306864433028,
        "value": "Macquarie Education Programs",
        "displayValue": "Macquarie Education Programs"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/wcl0MWlZL1)

Comment: Thanks, This seems to be the answer I was looking for and the jqplay data works, however, once I add cells that may not have a corresponding to_file or from_file value I get Cannot iterate over null (null)

Comment: @jimmy306 Please update your sample files accordingly to cover those cases.

Comment: thanks @pmf I editted the question to add the sample files

Comment: fixed with '?' 

[
    JOIN(
      INDEX(.[].cells; .[] | select(.columnId == 7408953102493572).displayValue);
      input[];
      .cells[] | select(.columnId == 5460306864433028).displayValue;
      (.[0].cells[] | select(.columnId == 5206337428711300)) +=
        (.[1][]**?** | select(.columnId == 5822630258337668) | del(.Column, .columnId))
    )[0]
  ]

Comment: @jimmy306 Yes, the problem is that in those cases `JOIN` matches to `null`, which breaks when trying to iterate over its elements `[]`. Probing with `?` does the job - either directly on the iteration `(…) += (.[1][]? | …)` ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/BfjTdhjTdr)), or on the whole update `(…) += (.[1][] | …)?` ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/orboG6EHvk)). Using `try` will work as well, as `EXP?` is just a shorthand for `try EXP`. If you wanted to be even more verbose, you could also insert a condition to the update, e.g. `select(.[1]) | (…) += (…)` ([Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/zFI_dgG8xA)).